# Was about to install Linux for the first time until Windows wanted to update when I restart

Tags: linux, windows, laptop, linux-mint

I was about to install Linux Mint for the first time and had just burned the iso file to my USB drive. When I went to restart my laptop, Windows only had the option 'update and restart'. Will Linux just install as usual and allow me to boot from the USB? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you are using an older OS where Secure Boot is not required, then what you are trying to do should work fine.   You can schedule updates to run overnight to avoid this issue.

Comment: I have Windows 8 and I think that version has Secure Boot, should I turn it off?

Comment: Yes in Windows 8 you can disable Secure Boot

Comment: And you should - for better results - install ALL pending updates for Windows, disable its Fast Startup feature and shutdown instead of just rebooting to the USB live/installation media, to assure the settings stick. Then boot from the USB and install as usual. Also recommended: Use native Windows tools to shrink one or more Windows partitions to make room for Linux in dual-boot (omit this step if Linux is to be installed in a different, blank, drive). Although the Mint installer can do the same this is STRONGLY discouraged because s*** might happen, especially with Fast Startup enabled.

Comment: Most modern versions of Linux, such as Ubuntu, can be installed **with secure boot enabled**. There is no reason to turn it off, unless there is a specific issue, and leaving Secure Boot enabled provides a bit more security.  Do stop *Fast Boot* in BIOS, because that leaves the Windows partition "dirty", and inaccessible: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275981/how-to-disable-fast-boot-when-bios-is-inaccessible

Comment: I have Linux with and without Secure Boot capability. Another way to get Mint running on your machine is via a Virtual Machine.  This avoids the issues you are having.